# Google Map inside a pod framework

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoapods

```
class MarkerItem: NSObject, GMUClusterItem {
  var details: Any
  var filters: Filter
  var icon: UIImage
  var name: String!
  var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
  var type: LocationService.LocationType
  var collapsed: Bool

  init(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String, icon: UIImage,
       filter: Filter, type: LocationService.LocationType, details: Any) {
    self.position = position
    self.name = name
    self.icon = icon
    self.filters = filter
    self.type = type
    self.details = details
    self.collapsed = true
  }
}
```

I am trying to create my own pod framework reusing some map views but I can't get Google maps to work. 
I keep getting

```
Use of undeclared type 'GMUClusterItem'
```

my imports

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GMUClusterItem` is from separate library, *Google-Maps-iOS-Utils*.

You need to install pod for it: `Google-Maps-iOS-Utils` and then import this library in your Swift file.

Comment: If you're using `use_frameworks!` in your `Podfile`, then Google Maps Utils won't work. See: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md